# Sum columns with similar names/prefixes in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

```
data <- data.frame (a_1 = 1:5, a_1.1 = 3:7, a_1.2 = 5:9, b_1 = 4:8, b_1.1= 7:11)
```

I want to have `a_1 = a_1 + a_1.1 + a_1.2`  `b_1 = b_1 + b_1.1` while still preserving the columns as `a_1, a_1.1, a_1.2, b_1, b_1.1`

I have several `words_number.number` columns, so I would like to have some function or a concise code snippet, but any solution would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "variant" of `split.default` using `tapply`

```
list2DF(
  tapply(
    as.list(data),
    gsub("\\..*", "", names(data)),
    function(x) rowSums(list2DF(x))
  )
)
```

gives

```
  a_1 b_1
1   9  11
2  12  13
3  15  15
4  18  17
5  21  19
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `split` the data with `split.default` on the substring of `names` and get the `rowSums` on the `list`

```
cbind(data, sapply(split.default(data, 
       sub("\\..*", "", names(data))), rowSums))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution that you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

names(data) %>%
  str_extract("^[:alpha:]") %>%
  unique() %>%
  map_dfc(~ data %>% select(contains(.x)) %>% 
            reduce(~ ..1 + ..2)) %>%
  set_names(~ letters[seq_along(.)]) %>%
  bind_cols(data) %>%
  relocate(c(a, b), .after = last_col())

# A tibble: 5 x 7
    a_1 a_1.1 a_1.2   b_1 b_1.1     a     b
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     5     4     7     9    11
2     2     4     6     5     8    12    13
3     3     5     7     6     9    15    15
4     4     6     8     7    10    18    17
5     5     7     9     8    11    21    19
```