# How to generate a column which counts non-NA values and another column with the average value on a subset of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-wrangling

I would like to add two columns in my dataframe, one column referring to the number of non-NA values within a subset of rows, and the other referring to the average value. Suppose I have the following data. Frame:

```
set. Seed(123)
df <- data.frame( id = 1:5,
                  var1_a = runif(1:5),
                  var1_b = runif(1:5),
                  var2_a = runif(1:5),
                  var2_b = runif(1:5))
df[, "var1_a"][ df[, "var1_a"] < 0.5 ] <- NA
df[, "var2_b"][ df[, "var2_b"] > 0.5 ] <- NA
```

Which is going to look like this:

```
  id    var1_a    var1_b    var2_a     var2_b
1  1        NA 0.0455565 0.9568333         NA
2  2 0.7883051 0.5281055 0.4533342 0.24608773
3  3        NA 0.8924190 0.6775706 0.04205953
4  4 0.8830174 0.5514350 0.5726334 0.32792072
5  5 0.9404673 0.4566147 0.1029247         NA
```

I would like to get the new columns for two subsets of columns identified as var1 and var2. This is going to lead me with 4 new columns, var1_count and var2_count which counts number of non-NA cells in the subset var1 and var2; and then another two columns avg_var1 and avg_var2 which calculates the average per row of subset columns var1 and var2.

I found a similar problem in the following link:

[Sum columns with similar names/prefixes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951736/sum-columns-with-similar-names-prefixes-in-r)

I tried to follow some solutions from this post:

```
list2DF(
  tapply(
    as.list(df),
    gsub("\\..*", "", names(df)),
    function(x) rowSums(list2DF(x))
  )
)
```

I also tried:

```
cbind(df, sapply(split.default(df, 
                  sub("\\..*", "", names(df))), rowSums))
```

I guess I don't understand what the `\\..*` means and I am getting the prefixes wrong. Also, since this is an example, my actual variables are not called var1 or var2, they have different name. Like, two of these variables are called "brand_m1_A" and "Brand_m1_B". Does that change the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, do a group by `summarise` to return the `mean` and count of non-NA elements, and join with the original data.  With `pivot_longer`, capture the characters (`(...)`) before the `_` and remove the characters that comes after including the `_` in column names to select only the 'var1', 'var2'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'), 
       names_to = ".value", names_pattern = "(.*)_.*") %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), 
     list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
      count = ~ sum(complete.cases(.x)))), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   left_join(df, .)
```

-output

```
 id    var1_a    var1_b    var2_a     var2_b var1_mean var1_count var2_mean var2_count
1  1        NA 0.0455565 0.9568333         NA 0.0455565          1 0.9568333          1
2  2 0.7883051 0.5281055 0.4533342 0.24608773 0.6582053          2 0.3497109          2
3  3        NA 0.8924190 0.6775706 0.04205953 0.8924190          1 0.3598151          2
4  4 0.8830174 0.5514350 0.5726334 0.32792072 0.7172262          2 0.4502771          2
5  5 0.9404673 0.4566147 0.1029247         NA 0.6985410          2 0.1029247          1
```

---

With the `split.default`, we need to use the regex `_.*` to remove the characters from `_`.  In addition, select only the columns that are numeric, i.e. remove the first 'id' column (`[-1]`)

```
cbind(df, lapply(split.default(df[-1], sub("_.*", "", 
   names(df[-1]))), \(x) 
    data.frame(mean = rowMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE), count = rowSums(!is.na(x)))))
```

-output

```
id    var1_a    var1_b    var2_a     var2_b var1.mean var1.count var2.mean var2.count
1  1        NA 0.0455565 0.9568333         NA 0.0455565          1 0.9568333          1
2  2 0.7883051 0.5281055 0.4533342 0.24608773 0.6582053          2 0.3497109          2
3  3        NA 0.8924190 0.6775706 0.04205953 0.8924190          1 0.3598151          2
4  4 0.8830174 0.5514350 0.5726334 0.32792072 0.7172262          2 0.4502771          2
5  5 0.9404673 0.4566147 0.1029247         NA 0.6985410          2 0.1029247          1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun ! My hero saving my day one more time. Just a quick question in your first solution. Is it necessary to group_by(id)? I don't understand why you are grouping the values row wise.

Comment: @VictorShin When you convert the wide format to long, it is no longer a single row per id, i.e. check `df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'), 
       names_to = ".value", names_pattern = "(.*)_.*")`, the values in var1_a, var1_b are combined to 2 rows for each id and similarly for var2_a, var2_b.  In this way, it is easier when there are many subsets for each 'var1', 'var2'